# How do I fix APT errors "W: Failed to fetch [...] Hash Sum mismatch"?

Tags: apt

I don't really know what happened, after reboot I got many crash messages, and if I would open Firefox or Synaptic, they would crash. Synaptic returns this:

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-security_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

Then crash icon on the top panel appeared, and there was some error about mergelist. I googled, and found this `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf` `sudo apt-get update` That didn't work. To be able to work in browser I deleted all files in `/var/lib/apt/lists`. If I try `sudo apt-get update`, I get this:

```
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ua.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_main_source_Sources Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ua.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_restricted_source_Sources Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ua.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_universe_source_Sources Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-security_main_source_Sources Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-security_universe_source_Sources Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-security_main_binary-i386_Packages Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I do not want to reinstall the system. How could I fix that? Thanks.

Some photos there. I can't make screenshots, it crashes: [Photo 1](http://f13.spaces.ru/p/091140200194019169045110055151170156215139169248/1372013299/65520531/0/8ef9cb35b92aa0cdcb3d9b9585ba6e5d/76ac501d727e13b60dcc0f924fd5f734/0/Roker112/100_1473-spaces.ru.jpg) [Photo 2](http://f11.spaces.ru/p/091140200194019169045110055151170156215139169248/1372013414/65520542/0/456b8fa1ee73f530e16f75322c38b8ba/0754f56243f77a85680cc616ace248e0/0/Roker112/100_1474-spaces.ru.jpg)

Comment: Did you recursively remove the contents of `/var/lib/apt/lists`? Or did you leave the `partial` subdirectory (including contents) there? Those files in there seem to be corrupted. The command you showed does not do that.

Comment: I removed partial also... I think if i will run `sudo apt-get update` it will reappear.

Comment: Then what command does that?

Comment: Nothing - you just said in the comments you removed `partial` as well. (though that was not in your question)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f` worked, but i have other problems now...

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that you deleted recursively `/var/lib/apt/lists`, which deleted the partial directory too. So, recreating the directory should solve the issue:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
```

Also, is possible that the mirror you are using have problems. Select another mirror and update again.

Comment: I already had the partial folder, but the chmod fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 8):

For me something is wrong in Ukrainian server! Changing to main automatically solves the problem. Please try different server if nothing of above was helpful.

Comment: This was correct for my error message `Sum mismatch`

Comment: Australian server occasionally has issues resulting in the above symptom, find a new server with: ```Ubuntu Software Centre > Edit > Software Sources > Download from > Other... > Select Best Server```

Comment: If you have doubts about which server to use, pick the "main server"