# How to install classicmenu-indicator or python-appindicator on Ubuntu 14.04 x64?

Tags: 64-bit, python, indicator, 14.04

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 x64.
When I try to install classicmenu-indicator it says about unresolved dependency python-appindicator
When I try to install python-appindicator it tries to install python-appindicator:i386 (Why? How to install 64 bit one?). It requires python:i386.
When I try to install python:i386 it requires to remove all python dependent packages including important for me.
How to install classicmenu-indicator or python-appindicator at this OS?
With best regards.
Viktor.

Comment: Where did you download classicmenu-indicator from? What version?  Please describe exactly how you are trying to install it.  Please add any replies to your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I opened Ubuntu software center, selected Edit -> Software Sources, selected Ubuntu Software tab and changed "Download from" to different server (Now it is the Main server).

And all problems are now fixed.

Also look at [How do I fix APT errors "W: Failed to fetch [...] Hash Sum mismatch"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311842/how-do-i-fix-apt-errors-w-failed-to-fetch-hash-sum-mismatch)