# Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade error

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I keep getting this messages :

```
W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ph.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_multiverse_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ph.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do it

The problem is that you deleted recursively /var/lib/apt/lists, which deleted the partial directory too. So, recreating the directory should solve the issue:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
```

copied from [How do I fix APT errors "W: Failed to fetch [...] Hash Sum mismatch"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311842/how-do-i-fix-apt-errors-w-failed-to-fetch-hash-sum-mismatch)

Comment: great! i got over that error message, now just waiting for the upgrade to complete!  fingers crossed...

Comment: did upgrade work??